# Создание промежуточных размеров изображений

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим если скопировать изображение с другого сайта на свой сайт с помощью php-функции copy, тогда создаётся только одно скопированное изображение в папке uploads.
Подскажите, как нужно копировать изображения с другого сайта, чтобы создавались все промежуточные размеры, которые выбраны в настройках медиафайлов?
т.е. 150x150, 300x300, 100x100 и т.д.

```
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $guid . $nameImg );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $guid . $nameImg );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Этот код только делает запись в базу данных.
Плагины не подходят, нужно сделать свой плагин

Comment: wp_generate_attachment_metadata() генерирует метаданные для картинки-вложения и создает промежуточные копии изображения - миниатюры всех зарегистрированных размеров. Источник https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_generate_attachment_metadata - так что дело не в коде, а где-то вне его. Например, нет прав на создание файлов в папке upoloads. Или неправильно передано имя файла. Нужна отладка, просмотр значений переменных.

Comment: >Например, нет прав на создание файлов в папке upoloads. Или неправильно передано имя файла.

Comment: ну если одно изображение копируется без промежуточных размеров, тогда логично, что права есть.  Подскажите, в вышеприведённом коде в функцию `wp_insert_attachment` и `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` передаются одни и те же пути к файлам. По идее имя файла идентично в вызовах двух функций. В чём может быть проблема ещё?

Comment: Из кода не следует, что копирование производится в этой или соседней функции. Копирование может быть вообще отдельным php-приложением, мне об этом не известно. А что в $attach_id и $attach_data?

Comment: >Из кода не следует, что копирование производится в этой или соседней функции

Comment: поверьте, следует. Этот код делал лично, поэтому эти строчки идут одна за другой.

Comment: >А что в $attach_id и $attach_data?

Comment: как-бы в коде это должно быть видно. Разве не так?

Comment: >Из кода не следует, что копирование производится в этой или соседней функции.

Comment: для чего вообще засорять тему? Я задал вопрос, при чём здесь следует или не следует? Логично предположить, что если нет других строк кода, тогда код идёт вместе, строка за строкой

Comment: Опять бесконечные комментарии, вместо ответов на вопросы. 1) в коде нет функции copy 2) не хотите отвечать, какие значения принимают переменные, о которых я спросил - дело ваше. Я не оракул. Берите отладчик в руки и разбирайтесь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58254/discussion-between-word-and-kagg-design).

Comment: решил проблему. неправильно добавил путь в функцию wp_generate_attachment_metadata

Comment: ну а я что говорил? проблема была вне этих 3 строчек кода